# How can I reconstruct the object hiearchy/references after XML deserialization in C#

Tags: c#, serialization, xna, xml-serialization, deserialization

I'm building a game project where there are simple container objects that can have children. I somehow need to save the "state" of the game and serializa to XML. Then I will simply be loading the game back by serializing XML, but I need to save the state of the objects, links, etc. What is the best practice to achieve this? To demonstrate, think of these:

```
GameObject Bag (ID 1234)
--------------
Sword (object ID 5678, some reference to another object in game: 0987)
```

and so on. I've got in-game references between objects and I need to preserve this state while saving/loading to XML. I have no problem with XML serialization itself in a simple scenario, but I don't know how to preserve the "links" between objects.

Comment: Does it actually *need* to be XML? XML is a tree format... Not many XML serializers support object references.

Comment: no, it doesn't have to be, but I'll be real glad if it is something built into .NET (not 3rd party libraries)

Comment: The only inbuilt ones to offer this are: BinaryFormatter, DataContractSerializer (via a specific constructor - not enabled by default), and NetDataContractSerializer. I'd agree with Anders that DataContractSerializer is the most appropriate of these. Various 3rd party serializers do too, but you make it clear you choose not to use those... Any reason why?

Comment: i don't want to get dependent to any 3rd party libraries that are not a part of original .net (and its official frameworks)..

Comment: well that's your call, but the community tools are actually pretty lively and excellent quality; and usually much faster with any fixes etc. up to you, of course.

Comment: they are good quality, it's no doubt, but i don't want to depend on too many different components from different sources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a serializer that supports references. DatacontractSerializer can do it for example. 
For xml, you can enable it in the DataContractSerializer for example
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sowmy/archive/2006/03/26/561188.aspx

Comment: ok, got the serializer working, but couldn't test it due to some other conflicts that i will resolve (i need a way to serialize delegates but that's another question on its own), anyway, is there anything extra to get references working, or will it just work when i could get it to work?

Comment: There are things to keep in mind when serializing delegates (e.g. not having references to objects you don't want to serialize of course). I'd also avoid serializing delegates as much as possible. For example, if object A always has a delegate to the Foo() method of an object, then you only need to store a reference to that object, and you can re-create the delegate again after deserialization.

Comment: yes, ok think of saving the state completely, there are lots of methods (with same signatures) and my delegate (lets have just one now for simplicity) is pointing to one of them. then i need a way to save the state, close my game, reopen it and load it back from scratch, but how do I store things such as CurrentAction = Walk (its a delegate) and load it back? is storing the string value and then loading it back the only way? how performance-efficient is it? and how is it done in practice? any way to make serializer do this automatically or do i need a string field in my class with method name?

Comment: Have an enum of possible actions, each implememnted by a delegate. Save only the enum. CurrentActionType = ActionType.Walk. Then you could either rebind to the method on deserialize, or actually never rebind at all but resolve from the value. For such a thing I don't think that the delegate is real "state", the state is only the information that the current action is "walk". So just serialize that and nothing else.

Comment: i actually got that part, i need a way to put it into the serialization/deserialization to make it automatic as much as possible

Answer (score 1):

Don't have real evidence in my hands, but had a friend of mine that used [YAML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML) for its Tree serialization, and was pretty sutisfied.

At the end of the article you will find also a references to .NET libraries available.

Hope this helps.

Comment: looks nice, but something built in would be more preferably for compatibility.

Comment: True, but consider this choice too (if have a time to do so), cause considering you're working on game, means you need high speed and low memory footprint.

Comment: actually, this seems really interesting: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/yamlparser.aspx